# Print different output based on integer without conditional statements

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to make a program takes 1 or 0 as an input, if the user chose one the program will print “open” , if 0 it will print out “close” , but I’m trying not to use conditional statements , i tried to use the while loop but it didn’t work

```py
x=int(input("enter 0 or 1"))
while x==1:
    print("open")
while x==0: 
    print("close")
```

Comment: But why to not use conditions?

Comment: It’s supposed to be a challenge

Comment: You can use your input as the index of a list. That won't require any if statements.

Comment: A challenge for who? Sounds like you're cheating if you're asking others to adhere to such limited requirements to solve your problem

Comment: There're plenty of options: `("close", "open")[your_input]`, `your_input and "open" or "close"`

Comment: Why would i cheat its our summer vacation I’m not studying anything i just saw it online and tried to solve it 

Comment: _Tried to solve it_. As per [help] you should [edit] your question to include what you actually tried

Comment: Ok I’ll edit it

Answer (score 2):

One way you can do it is by creating a dictionary that holds the options:

```
options = {0: "close", 1: "open"}

var = input()
try:
    print(options[int(var)])
except:
    print("Please enter a valid number (0 or 1)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to using branching could be to use a dictionary to map possible inputs to their output, and then just print the value corresponding to the user input

```
resultMap = {1: "open", 0: "close"}
answer = int(input("0 or 1:"))
print(resultMap[answer])
```

(of course, check if input is valid in a real scenario)

Don't overthink it, though, for a zero-or-one, an `if-else` is fine, and usually more readable.

I'd recommend the dictionary approach in at least those two scenarios,:

1. you have many if-elif
2. you want your program to be configurable (the mapping dictionary could be generated by reading some config file easily)

Comment: Why to not use string keys?

Comment: that's perfectly possible as well. That was more to match the same logic in OP's code, and to focus on the actual problem described without adding too many discrepancy (assuming OP could be a beginner)

Answer (score 0):

In your "challenge", all you are doing is mapping input to output.

And giving that the required mapping is very simple - consecutive zero based integers to strings, a simple list will suffice:

```
out_map = [ "close", "open" ]

choice = input()
try:
    print(out_map[int(choice)]
except:
    print("You must enter zero or one!")
```

There is however a simple way to create true code branches without using `if`:

```
while condition == "option a":
    condition = None
    # do some code for "option a"

while condition == "option b":
    condition = None
    # do some code for "option b"
```

To really solve such a challenge, you must carefully consider all language tools that change the execution path, including but not limited to loops, function calls, and exceptions.